# How to order the harvesting of file before compilation?

Tags: msbuild, wix, tfsbuild

I use the [_PublishedApplications](http://www.nuget.org/packages/publishedapplications) to generate the structure in the TFS Build Server. After this, I use the `<HeatDirectory>` in the WiX project to correctly harvest the content of _PublishedApplications folder. But my problem is the order during build.

If I use the `<HeatDirectory>` inside `<Target Name="BeforeBuild">` it doesn't include the binaries copied to the _PublishedApplications, as the harvesting is executed before the publish (file copy).

If I change the target to `BeforeCompile` the compilation doesn't succeed because there is no file in first place. Here is the code for the WiX project (the relevant part of it):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Product.wxs" />
    <Compile Include="Autogenerated.wxs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SimpleProject\SimpleProject.csproj">
      <Name>SimpleProject</Name>
      <Project>{GUID}</Project>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <DoNotHarvest>True</DoNotHarvest>
      <RefProjectOutputGroups>Binaries</RefProjectOutputGroups>
      <RefTargetDir>INSTALLFOLDER</RefTargetDir>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />
  <Target Name="BeforeCompile">
    <HeatDirectory OutputFile="Autogenerated.wxs" Directory="$(Sources)"
                   PreprocessorVariable="var.SimpleProject.TargetDir" 
                   AutogenerateGuids="true" SuppressRegistry="true"
                   ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" DirectoryRefId="INSTALLFOLDER"
                   ComponentGroupName="ComponentGroup_Core" 
                   SuppressRootDirectory="true" />
  </Target>
```

**Question**

How can I execute the harvesting after the binaries are copied to _PublishedApplications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I build my solution using the following command:

```
msbuild SimpleInstaller.sln /p:OutDir=C:\Temp\Output\ /v:diag > C:\Temp\Log.txt
```

This will output all log to a text file. You can use the [MSBuild logger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470.aspx) instead.

Then I found when you build a C# project, the target `Compile` in file *Microsoft.Common.targets* is invoked. This target has an attribute `DependsOnTarget` which contains a reference to target `BeforeCompile`.

I can override this target `BeforeCompile` in my own C# project, just by adding the following code at the end of it (file *.csproj*):

```
  ...
  <Target Name="BeforeCompile">
    <!-- custom action. -->
  </Target>
</Project>
```

But the problem is my WiX project cannot override the `BeforeCompile` target because this target isn't defined for WiX projects. You can check this in the *wix2010.targets* file. The target `Compile` only has dependence upon targets `PrepareForBuild`, `ResolveWixExtensionReferences` and `GenerateCompileWithObjectPath`.

My solution was to identify an alternative to `BeforeCompile` which is the `Harvest` target. My WiX project (*.wixproj*) has the following target now:

```
<Target Name="Harvest">
  <HeatDirectory OutputFile="Autogenerated.wxs" Directory="$(Sources)"
                 PreprocessorVariable="var.SimpleProject.TargetDir" 
                 AutogenerateGuids="true" SuppressRegistry="true"
                 ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" DirectoryRefId="INSTALLFOLDER"
                 ComponentGroupName="ComponentGroup_Core" 
                 SuppressRootDirectory="true" />
</Target>
```

All this problem occurred because my first project in the solution was the WiX project and only then I added the C# projects. For this reason the `BeforeBuild` was being executed before everything else.

Another solution to solve this issue is to edit the solution file (*.sln*) and move the WiX project declaration in the beginning of the solution file to the end of all project declarations (not the end of the solution file). Then the `BeforeBuild` of the WiX project will be executed after the _PublishedApplications folder is created by the C# project.

This manual edit is required because if you change the Project Build Order you are actually changing the project references (at least in the solution file), but the target `BeforeBuild` is called anyway before the `ResolveProjectReferences` which is the responsible for invoking the build of any references.

This is the project declaration that should be after all others:

```
Project("GUID") = "SimpleInstaller", "SimpleInstaller\SimpleInstaller.wixproj", "GUID"
EndProject
```

My recommendation is still to use `Harvest` target as it is independent of any changes in the solution file.

Comment: You should not edit your solution file directly. There is an option in VS to do that. Please review the update in my answer.

Comment: Even if you change the Project Build Order, when you execute the build, the first target is the first project in the file. Then, the BeforeBuild for that first project is called. Only after the BeforeBuild is called, the ResolveProjectReferences is called, so even if you change the build order by adding project references, it will not work in this particular case.

Comment: I have a solution file (VS 2013u5 - 12.0.40629.0) where the .wixproj is defined last (of the project refs) in the file, but I'm still observing the behavior where the BeforeBuild target of the .wixproj is called before the dependent projects are built.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is add a project reference from your installer project to your application project. This will force the application to build and be available for your installer project.

**You can verify the build sequence of the projects if you right click your solution under VisualStudio and click the "Project Build Order...", if you need to change the order you need to configure the Project dependencies.**

Then do something like this in your installer project:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <RootDir>{PATH TO _PublishedApplications FOLDER}</RootDir>
        <HarvestDirectoryNoLogo>true</HarvestDirectoryNoLogo>
        <HarvestDirectorySuppressAllWarnings>false</HarvestDirectorySuppressAllWarnings>
        <HarvestDirectoryTreatWarningsAsErrors>false</HarvestDirectoryTreatWarningsAsErrors>
        <HarvestDirectoryTreatSpecificWarningsAsErrors>
        </HarvestDirectoryTreatSpecificWarningsAsErrors>
        <HarvestDirectoryVerboseOutput>false</HarvestDirectoryVerboseOutput>
        <HarvestDirectoryAutogenerateGuids>false</HarvestDirectoryAutogenerateGuids>
        <HarvestDirectoryGenerateGuidsNow>true</HarvestDirectoryGenerateGuidsNow>
        <HarvestDirectorySuppressFragments>true</HarvestDirectorySuppressFragments>
        <HarvestDirectorySuppressUniqueIds>false</HarvestDirectorySuppressUniqueIds>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        <ItemGroup>
            <HarvestDirectory Include="$(RootDir)">
                <Transforms>
                </Transforms>
                <ComponentGroupName>MyComponent</ComponentGroupName>
                <DirectoryRefId>WebSiteRoot</DirectoryRefId>
                <PreprocessorVariable>var.RootDir</PreprocessorVariable>
                <SuppressCom>false</SuppressCom>
                <SuppressRegistry>false</SuppressRegistry>
                <SuppressRootDirectory>true</SuppressRootDirectory>
                <KeepEmptyDirectories>true</KeepEmptyDirectories>
            </HarvestDirectory>
        </ItemGroup>
        <HeatDirectory 
            NoLogo="$(HarvestDirectoryNoLogo)" 
            SuppressAllWarnings="$(HarvestDirectorySuppressAllWarnings)" 
            SuppressSpecificWarnings="$(HarvestDirectorySuppressSpecificWarnings)" 
            ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" 
            TreatWarningsAsErrors="$(HarvestDirectoryTreatWarningsAsErrors)" 
            TreatSpecificWarningsAsErrors="$(HarvestDirectoryTreatSpecificWarningsAsErrors)" 
            VerboseOutput="$(HarvestDirectoryVerboseOutput)" 
            AutogenerateGuids="$(HarvestDirectoryAutogenerateGuids)" 
            GenerateGuidsNow="$(HarvestDirectoryGenerateGuidsNow)" 
            OutputFile="$(IntermediateOutputPath)_%(HarvestDirectory.Filename)_dir.wxs" 
            SuppressFragments="$(HarvestDirectorySuppressFragments)" 
            SuppressUniqueIds="$(HarvestDirectorySuppressUniqueIds)" 
            Transforms="%(HarvestDirectory.Transforms)" 
            Directory="@(HarvestDirectory)" 
            ComponentGroupName="%(HarvestDirectory.ComponentGroupName)" 
            DirectoryRefId="%(HarvestDirectory.DirectoryRefId)" 
            KeepEmptyDirectories="%(HarvestDirectory.KeepEmptyDirectories)" 
            PreprocessorVariable="%(HarvestDirectory.PreprocessorVariable)" 
            SuppressCom="%(HarvestDirectory.SuppressCom)" 
            SuppressRootDirectory="%(HarvestDirectory.SuppressRootDirectory)" 
            SuppressRegistry="%(HarvestDirectory.SuppressRegistry)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

I generated this code based on the documentation of the [HeatDirectory Task](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/task_reference/heatdirectory.html) and I use it in real projects.

Comment: This is exactly the same I did and it doesn't work because the task in the NuGet _PublishedApplications package that copies the output is performed after the harvesting. It is independent of the project's reference.